# $_POST is empty as a result of AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

***The problem:*** var_dump($_POST['day']) is **NULL**, var_dump($b); is string(0) ""
As a result - return empty json

HTML Form with checkboxes

```
<form id="filter">
   <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="1"> 
   <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="2">
   <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="3"> 
</form>
```

JS

```
var a = 0;
var b = 5;
var c = $( "#filter" ).serialize();
var Data = 'a=' + a + '&' + 'b=' + b + '&' + c;
var process = false;
$.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: Data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        process = true;
    }
});
```

script.php  var_dump($_POST['day']) is NULL

```
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $_POST['b'];
$c = implode(',', $_POST['day']); // Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($c) - 1) . '?'; // Warning: Second argument has to be greater than or equal to 0
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE day IN ($in) ASC LIMIT :a, :b";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($с, [$a, $b]);
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Proper way of setting the POST DATA from javascript `data: {a: a, b: b, day: c},`

Comment: You didn't create a `day` variable in the JS you created a `c`

Comment: Actually you didn't even create a `c` variable now I look closer

Comment: `+ '&day=' + c;` if you want to do it that way

Comment: @RiggsFolly the `c` comes from `serialize()` which is already key=pair values

Comment: If i dont use prepared statements and pdo my code works, but with Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: So do a simple `print_r($_POST)` to see what you have actually passed to the PHP code

Comment: print_r($_POST) - Array ( )

Comment: `$stmt->execute` takes a single argument, you're passing 2

Comment: $stmt->execute(array($c, $a, $b));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE day IN ($in) LIMIT ?, ?";

But again dont work!

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = [];

$a = (int) $_POST['a'];
$b = (int) $_POST['b'];

$c = array_filter( (array) $_POST['day'] );

if ( !empty($c) )
{
 $c = implode(',', $_POST['day']);
 $c = explode(",", $c);
 $in = str_repeat("?,", count($c) - 1) . '?';
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE day IN ($in) LIMIT ?, ?";
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $params = array_merge($c, [$a, $b]);
 $stmt->execute($params);
 $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
 $result = $data;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```